# HTML grouped inputs return 'array' instead of array of their values in PHP

Tags: php, html

I've grouped elements together before using the bracket notation but I must be overlooking something. Maybe another pair of eyes (or thousands) can spot why this is backfiring.

```
foreach ( $record as $field => $value) {

if(strpos($value , '~') !== FALSE){ //All drop down lists are separated by ~
    $rows_of_dlist .= '<tr>';

$stored_field = explode ( "mlljx", $value );
$stored_field [0] = trim ( $stored_field [0] ); //Title of the list
$stored_field [1] = trim ( $stored_field [1] ); //Values of the list


$dlist = explode ( '~', $stored_field [1] );

foreach ( $dlist as $dlist ) {
    $list_values .= " <td><input type='checkbox' name='selected_option[]'value='$dlist'/> &nbsp; $dlist</td>";
}

$rows_of_dlist .= "<td align = 'center'>$stored_field[0]</td> $list_values</tr>";


<form id="all" name="all" method="POST" action="$page_name?page_view=report" >
    <table align="center" width = "100%" border = "2">  
        <th colspan = "1">Name Of Custom Drop-down List</th>
        <th colspan = "10">Drop-list Values</th>
        $rows_of_dlist      
        <tr>
            <td align = 'center' colspan='10'>
                        <input type="submit" value="Make PDF" name = "make_pdf"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

After the values are posted, I test the POST array:

```
  var_dump($_POST);
  exit;
```

Then it says `$_POST['selected_option']` is 'Array' even if I select only one box.

Comment: What is the generated HTML source (before submitting the form)?

Comment: Do you need a space between name='selected_option[]' and value='$dlist'/> ?

Comment: if I understand correctly the HTML is whats already posted. We use templates so I would pace the form  in a variable and magic would happen in the background. I dynamically build the table. Its a very simple page, which is why this is driving me nuts.

Sadly the space doesn't fix it but nice catch though.

Answer (score 1):

I think this wrong:

```
foreach ( $dlist as $dlist ) {
```

Shouldn't it be something like

```
foreach ( $dlist as $element) { ... do something with each $element ... }
```

Comment: Yeah, or *anything* other than `$dlist`...  `foreach ($array as $array) { echo $array; }` ends in heartache.

Comment: Sadly no that doesn't fix it but I need to break that habit.